# Updating MySQL row with values from another table using PDOs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table like the one below that currently has no values for `rating`, `lib_id` or `votes`.

**library**

```
id | title | year | rating | votes  | lib_id |
---------------------------------------------
1  | book1 | 1999 |        |        |       |
2  | book2 | 2010 |        |        |       |
3  | book3 | 2009 |        |        |       |
4  | book4 | 2007 |        |        |       |
5  | book5 | 1987 |        |        |       |
```

I then have the classifications table which looks like this.

**classifications**

```
id   | title   | year | rating | votes  | lib_id |
---------------------------------------------
108  | book154 | 1929 |        |        |        |
322  | book23  | 2011 |        |        |        |
311  | book3   | 2009 |  9.3   |  4056  |  10876 |
642  | book444 | 2001 |        |        |        |
533  | book567 | 1981 |        |        |        |
```

It can happen that entries in the library table may not appear in the classifications table and vice-versa. There can also be the possibility that the title of the book is not unique. So what I want to do is go through each row in the library table, take the `title` and `year` columns, go to the `classifications` table and find the row that has these two values, retrieve the corresponding `rating`, `votes` and `lib_id` columns and update the entry in the library table.

I also want to use PDOs. Below is a non-working example of what i'm trying to achieve.

```
$update_vals_STH = 
$DBH->prepare(
   "UPDATE library SET lib_id=?, rating=?, votes=? 
    FROM (SELECT lib_id, rating, votes) 
    FROM classifications WHERE title=? AND year=?";
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm quite new to MySQL and have been struggling with this one for a while.

Comment: If you want to do this with one SQL Query without coding and interating in looper over rows, you definatelly don't need `?` operator, because it's only for binding values in your application logic, not database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join tables on update statement too.

```
UPDATE  library a
        INNER JOIN classifications b
            ON  a.title = b.title AND
                a.year = b.year
SET     a.rating = b.rating,
        a.votes = b.votes,
        a.lib_id = b.lib_id
// WHERE    clause                   // if you want to have extra condition.
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a73f/1)

**UPDATE**

For better performance, you need to add indexes on the following field.

```
ALTER TABLE library ADD INDEX (title, year);
ALTER TABLE classifications ADD INDEX (title, year);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. When I run the query it just keeps running. I stopped the script after 10 minutes and there was no change to the table. Perhaps i should have mentioned that my library table is 9000 rows and my classifications table is around 260,000 rows. Would this make a difference to the query?

Comment: @garethdn it is working but unfornately performing `full table scan`. You need to add index on the columns, please wait i'll update the answer :)

Comment: have some feedback if the indexes doesn't improve the performance.

Comment: works great, query only takes about 2 seconds now. thanks again